# Clone a google cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have google cloud VM with Ubuntu installed along with various services and libraries. I need to make a similar bootable VM with the same OS and all the data, libraries etc in the already configured VM. How do I clone the VM with these requirements?

I tried to create an image from the already existing VM and could not SSH into it.

So I retraced my installations step by step trying to figure out which step is breaking the image.
I created an Ubuntu(18.04) VM and used that to create an image. The instance I created using the image did allow me to SSH into.

Next installed Ubuntu desktop and xorg server and created an image after that. Using that image, I created a new VM and tried to SSH into it.
But unfortunately, the SSH connection could not be established. So I think it is these installations that are causing the error if it is not some sort of system error.

Below are the exact commands I ran to install these after creating an Ubuntu(18.04) VM:

```
 sudo passwd username
  sudo su -
  passwd
  apt update && apt upgrade -y
  adduser username root
  adduser username admin
  adduser username sudo

  apt-get install ubuntu-desktop -y
  apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-dummy
  
  nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and pasted the following into the .conf file

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "dummy"
  EndSection
  Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync 31.5-48.5
    VertRefresh 50-70
  EndSection
  Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1600x900"
    EndSubSection
  EndSection
```

After this state, I created the image using which I could not instantiate a VM that I could SSH into.

Comment: Create an image. You can then create one or more virtual machines from that image. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your VM ready and running; backup your image as per this [GCP document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images). Follow the guidelines before you begin the process which were mentioned in the document like updating Google cloud CLI setting default region and zone and for general image guidelines.
Few networking features may require guest operating system mode. You can also check how to export a custom image to [cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image).
You can also consider the [Snapshot Approach](https://geekflare.com/clone-google-cloud-vm/).

Comment: I actually tried the machine image, image and snapshot path but I can't SSH into the VM. The error that I think is causing this that I got from console log: OSConfigAgent Critical main.go:100: Error parsing metadata, agent cannot start: network ssh into gcp vm

Comment: could you please check this [once](https://serverfault.com/questions/982517/why-cant-i-access-metadata-server-of-gcp-instance#:~:text=This%20can%20be%20caused%20by,Compute%20Engine%20%2D%3E%20VM%20instances.)

Comment: I talked to google support and the problem is due to the network interface card not being there in the new instance. Although, the cause is not yet identified I was told that it was probably due to some applications that I had installed on the VM.

Comment: @Traique Please try with a blank VM. If it works; try by adding libraries one by one. So, we can know the problem.

Comment: so I tried to follow your suggestion and I could SSH into the VM created from the custom image worked initially but couldn't after some installations. I will update the question with the deatils.

Comment: @Tarique please refer [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/946224/google-cloud-services-unable-to-ssh-into-instance-at-all). I strongly doubt about your firewall rules and refer this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QGpHQ2SyG8) as well.

Comment: @Tarique can you confirm about the status of your issue please.

Comment: I contacted google cloud support and provided them with the details of my setup and installations. They were able to replicate the issue and are investigating it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this process](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#creating_a_custom_image) in order to create the image exactly as the one you have already set up and you know is working correctly. As you may already know, this is a custom image so they are available only to your Cloud project. You can create a custom image from boot disks and other images if you would like also. Then, use the custom image to create an instance.

I will also suggest you to give a look at this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#custom_images) which would give you a deeper knowledge on the task.

Regards,

Comment: I have tried this and machine image process and snapshot as well. Still can't SSH into the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Just spin up a new container from a [disk snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots), if you need an exact copy. And if you cannot SSH, you may either not have a SSH public key provisioned, no external IP assigned, or `:22` closed.

`gcloud ssh` always works. One can as well provision project-wide SSH keys, which all VM in the project will inherit then. The documentation below: [About VM metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview) explains this all in detail.

My personal favorite are rather [startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux), which describe the configuration, instead of copying it.
And it's not so difficult to get started with these: `cat ~/.bash_history > rocky8_startup.sh`. In a software-defined data-center, it might make sense to use software-defined configurations (one simply cannot alternate the installation per VM instance, when starting with a disk snapshot).

---

`xserver-xorg-video-dummy` is questionable, because one can enable display device -
but unless recording the screen, this driver might still suffice; eg. for VNC sessions.